# Completion of JS code in Emacs

Tags: json, emacs, autocomplete

I have almost no experience in JS dev, but I have to learn it, and I'd want my Emacs to help me discover functions callable on objects.

Can Emacs complete `View.` with the right functions -- to be found in JSON controllers?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for expanding Emacs into a JS friendly tool.

Here are some options:

https://truongtx.me/2014/02/23/set-up-javascript-development-environment-in-emacs

http://xiaohanyu.me/oh-my-emacs/modules/ome-javascript.html